# How can I totally disable SSL authentication in puppet?

Tags: ssl, puppet

In our environment,we often reinstall our machine with the same hostname.
So,everytime I sync the configuration vai puppet,SSL authentication will fail.
How can I totally disable SSL authentication?

Comment: think about masterless solution, with that, you needn't care of ssl certificate between puppet agent and master.

Answer (score 3):

The assumption that connections are authenticated and identified through trusted SSL certificates runs very deep in Puppet's core. There is no way to make Puppet run through unencrypted channels only.

Things you can try:

- holding on to signed certificates and getting them back onto machines just when they are re-provisioned
- creating a hook that will make the master revoke the old certificate when a machine is decommissioned/recommissioned

With the latter approach, the signing of fresh certificates will be eased considerably. You might even implement an autosigning scheme, although that is tricky to do in a secure fashion.

Comment: Yes,we create a python script.When a machine is recommissioned,cobbler will invoke the script to login to puppet master to clean the certificate.